# ngFor should be slower when passing the options to child?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I have created a select component because I'll have tons of select inputs in my code. I'm passing to this component a huge list of "1550" rows like behind.

```
<app-selectfield
 class="col-sm-5"
 [name]="'city'"
 [(value)]="city"
 [options]="listOfCities"
></app-selectfield>
```

This list should be requested when the user opens the modal (this input select is into that modal). Idk why, but when I try to open this modal, it takes 2-3 seconds to show. The big question is, when I just use the select into the parent component and don't pass the data into one child component, the modal don't take any time to open.

Child:

```
<select
  type="text"
  [(ngModel)]="value"
  (ngModelChange)="valueChange.emit($event)"
>
  <option [ngValue]="undefined" disabled  selected>-- {{placeholder}} --</option>
  <option *ngFor="let option of options" [ngValue]="option">{{option[valor]}}</option>
</select>
```

Sorry for bad english

**Update: This is where I open the modal (in the parent component)**

```
openModal(item:any) {
  if(item.id) {
    this.companyService.getCompany(item.id)
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.company = res;
        this.company.uf = this.company.city.uf;

        this.globalService.getCities(this.company.uf.id)
          .subscribe((res:any) => this.listOfCities = res);
    });
  } else {
    this.company = {};
  }

  if(this.ufList.length <= 1) {
    this.globalService.getUf()
      .subscribe((res: any[]) => res.map(response => this.UfList.push(response)));
  }
  this.lgModal.show();
}
```

The children just takes care about render the items.

Comment: I think the problem is that the data is being loaded in the same event handler method that opens the modal, could you post how do you open the modal and when are you fetching the list of items?

Comment: @OsmanCea updated!

Comment: Is there a way you can set up a demo? There's a couple of things I'd like to try with your current setup... What are you using for your modal? Bootstrap? Is it a custom component? Can you show the template of `parent component`?

Comment: I'll try, but i cant use the http requests... Also I'm using ngx for Bootstrap components.